# What does り have to do with this?

Tags: grammar, usage, translation

So I asked some Japanese guy if he really meant something (about speaking in certain language) with 本当ですか and I got this as an answer:

> 実はしゃべれるわけじゃなかったりする

I understand what わけではない means, but what's with that り? How to properly translate this sentence?

Comment: It's たり. http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/139246/m0u/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chocolate's link will teach you the usual usage of たり, but it might still not be clear how it's used in this case. In this case, it's used basically to make an excuse or to beat around the bush or something like that. The literal translation might be something like

> In fact, I can't speak [the language] among other things

but the real meaning is closer to

> In fact, I kinda can't speak [the language]